# Have second user in window and not whole desktop

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I have to use a different user on my mac for some tasks which include regular switching between users. I know about quick user switching, but this has two limitations for me:

1. I have to enter the password each time I switch users
2. I would like to have the second user in a window and not the whole desktop (as in a virtual machine)

I would prefer the solution 2.

Is there a way of logging in to the local machine as user2 while being logged in as user1 so that the desktop of user2 is shown in a window and I can easily switch? Do I have to use VNC or is there a build in option which I could (ab)use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I have found a solution using Real-vnc.

1. Install Real-vnc **version 5.3.2** from [their download site](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/macosx/#older-versions). It is important to **not** install a newer version, as this seems to be the last version which supports User-mode for the server without a paid subscription!
2. As the [server stops when a fast user switch occurs](https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/453/4/vnc-server-in-user-mode-stops-on-fast-user-switch-under-mac-os-x) it is important to change the following setting (from the [real-vnc knowledge base](https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/453/4/vnc-server-in-user-mode-stops-on-fast-user-switch-under-mac-os-x)):

> ... setting the option "StopUserModeOnSwitchOut" to "No" in the Expert tab
>   (VNC Server > Options > Expert tab).

3. Quit `VNC server` (this is the service). We don't need the global `VNC server` service as we will use the `User Mode`.
4. Now switch to the other user and login
5. Start `VNC server` (user mode). If you want to, you can add it to the `Login Items` to have it autostart upon login.
6. Switch back to your main user
7. use `Screen Sharing` app or the `VNC Viewer` app to connect to `localhost`. It is possible that you have to set a password in the VNC server, but I am not sure (the viewer will tell you).

That's it - it works perfectly for me, even with multiple monitor setup.

What I didn't manage, was to setup that the viewer uses both monitors - but I can live with that.